# Minecraft Bedrock Edition default blocks

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

Is there any documentation of the original Minecraft blocks behavior JSON? I'm not looking for `blocks.json`, I'm looking for individual vanilla blocks and their components such as `stone.json`, `glass.json`, etc. I can't find it in the Vanilla Behavior Pack, and poking around the apk file doesn't seem to be helping either. It would be really helpful as a guideline when making custom blocks in addons.

Comment: There aren't (bc they are hard-coded into the game) but in a bit I can write some for you because those blocks are so simple they should be fairly easy to recreate

Comment: That's unfortunate. Such a list would be helpful.

Comment: Ugh! I can't seem to find anything that indicates the correct tool right now, so maybe I'll come back later but as for right now looks like I can't, sorry :(

Comment: That's alright, thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't modify the behavior of the blocks in the `minecraft` namespace. I followed [the Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/customblock) on custom block creation and adjusted the data to be directed at a sand block:

```
{
    "format_version": "1.16.0",
    "minecraft:block": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "minecraft:sand",
            "is_experimental": false,
            "register_to_creative_menu": true
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:destroy_time": 1,
            "minecraft:explosion_resistance": 5,
            "minecraft:friction": 0.6,
            "minecraft:flammable": {
                "flame_odds": 0,
                "burn_odds": 0
            },
            "minecraft:map_color": "#FFFFFF",
            "minecraft:block_light_absorption": 0,
            "minecraft:block_light_emission": 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior pack will import successfully, but you'll be greeted by the following error message when loading it into a world:

> [Blocks][error]-block_definitions | Taco's Test Pack | blocks/sand.json | Identifier not allowed to use Minecraft namespace

Subsequently, it is not possible to customize the behavior of default blocks.

Comment: I know you can't use the minecraft namespace, and I know the documentation has all the properties available, but what I'm looking for is the properties of the blocks. I might be able to reconstruct them by trial and error, but is there anything that tells me directly, for example, "the default stone block has a hardness of 1"?

Comment: @404NameNotFound The new Minecraft Wiki has info on all of the vanilla blocks: here is the page for stone: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone showing it has a hardness of 1.5 and a blast resistance of 6.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Thanks, it's been 2 years so I don't remember if I checked the wiki back then, but the old wiki seems to have that information too. Either way, since it's only one value, I assume it means they have the same properties in both Java and Bedrock? Not that it makes sense to have them different, but such discrepancies are not impossible.